# Magento: paypal Standard payment not redirecting to Magento Success page after Payment complete

Tags: magento, paypal, magento-1.7, payment-gateway

I am facing problem with paypal standard payment. Everything is fine until success page.
when customer complete payment. then paypal is not redirecting to magento success page. it is still is in paypal page. but charging from customer paypal account and no payment information is coming to magento backend and thats why it is showing order as pending.

if anyone can give solution then it will be very helpful.

thanks

Comment: FYI, Magento now has its own StackExchange site: http://magento.stackexchange.com

Comment: i have faced same issue my site. can any one post me actual answer? Thanks.

Comment: Finally I got solution, If your paypal account is business account you have change paypal setting from setting option, IPN

Answer (score 2):

1. Paypal has some configuration seting at paypal account level for auto return.
   Set this to true.
2. Also make sure Paypal IPN is set to true.

These two once done should sort our your problem.

If not then you need to collect whats posted to paypal and what response is received from paypal.

Answer (score 0):

Paypal standard is not providing this type of redirection, so it is better to use Express checkout instead of PayPal standard version.